# Reducing Size of SVG Maps Generated from GIS Data

Tags: svg, gis

So, I downloaded GIS data from one my state government's websites, http://rfa.sc.gov/mapping/gisdata, and I popped it into a free GIS tool called GrassGIS and exported the SVG data. The issue is that the code it generated is hundreds of lines long per path, and there are over 100 paths.

My text editor struggles with functioning when I have it open, and so I've had to isolate it to it's own HTML file and just load it in with PHP. But I still have to work within the file, and the ability to collapse sections, which is necessary to navigate through it, frequently stops working I assume because it overwhelms the text editor. The file by itself is 7,324 KB.

I've tried pasting the code of individual paths into various SVG simplifier/minimizer websites, but I get error messages, I'm guessing because it's too big.

Does anyone know of any solutions in dealing with files like these, or simplifying them? I don't need the precise GIS data, which I'm assuming is why it's so large, I just need the rough shapes the data makes. Any websites or methods that could simplify the shapes, or free GIS software that might export a better SVG file would be appreciated. Any suggestions at all.

Comment: Asking for tools, libraries, or off-site resources is off-topic in here

Comment: The help center states I can ask for software tools commonly used by developers, and as long as I state what my problem is and what I have done to fix it, which I have. My problem is that my SVG code is too long, and I have tried fixing it by putting it in random SVG simplifier/minimizer websites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After downloading your data, run GRASS [v.generalize](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/v.generalize.html) to simplify the geometries.

A better problem statement may provide better solutions—I can't actually understand why you want to manually walk through an SVG (or even text) representation, as opposed to say looking at the attributes in a table view (e.g. in QGIS), without any kind of export to SVG.